# How to fill the none values to a list of tuples using Python

Tags: python

I want to write a code that can merge list a&b to get list c by filling list a with tuples, of which tuple[0] is none and tuple[1] is the values that are in b but not in a[index][1]. For instance,

```py
a=[(1,None),(2,4),(3,6),(4,None),(5,9)];
b=[4,5,6,7,9]
```

The desired c should be

```py
c=[(1,None),(2,4),(None,5),(3,6),(4,None),(None,7),(5,9)]
```

I wrote a simple code as below that appended (None,5) at the end of the list. My actual intention is to insert it as the order of list b (I'm not sure how). Also, it seems to be inefficient as the number of elements in each list grows.

```
import itertools
a=[(1,None),(2,4),(3,6),(4,None),(5,9)]
b=[4,5,6,7,9]
for elem2 in b:
    for elem1 in a:
        if elem1[1]==elem2:
            #print(str(elem2) +'is in.')
            break
    else:
        a.append((None,elem2))
print(a)
```

Is there a special function that can achieve the merge?

Comment: You're literally appending. Why would it not appear at the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the elements ordered by second value then you need to implement a merge operation. The general idea is "keep picking the lower element and add that".
If the elements are sorted also there is no need to use a `set` for knowing if an element is present or not:

```
c = []
ia = ib = 0
while ia < len(a) and ib < len(b):
    if a[ia][1] == b[ib]:
        # same second element, a wins
        c.append(a[ia])
        ia += 1
        ib += 1
    elif a[ia][1] is None or a[ia][1] < b[ib]:
        # a element is smaller and comes first
        c.append(a[ia])
        ia += 1
    else:
        # b element is smaller and comes first
        v.append((None, b[ib]))
        ib += 1
# at the end may be there are extra a elements, add all of them at once
if ia < len(a):
    c += a[ia:]
# or there may be extra b elements
while ib < len(b):
    c.append((None, b[ib:]))
    ib += 1
```

Comment: His code already does what your code does...it appends missing items.  He wants to insert missing items into the right place in the list so that the list remains sorted by the second tuple values.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I'm not familiar with the set function but building the set definitely seems to be a simpler approach. However, when I run the code, an error message (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable) occurred at the line "for x, y in b". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @MollyZhou: my code was wrong in two aspect, considered `b` to be a list of tuples too when instead are just the second numbers. Moreover it appended all the elements at the end: it was faster than your code but still not keeping elements in order. Current answer is instead the "merge" operation that is needed to keep the sequence correct.

Comment: I understand the current version of your code, except that it does not seem to work when a[ia][1]==None as it cannot be compared with integer type.

Comment: @MollyZhou: You are right, in Python 3 it's a runtime error trying to compare `None` and numbers with `<` (equality comparison is ok, however). In the fixed version `None` is considered to be less than any number and those tuple will remain at the beginning of `c`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code solves my problem perfectly:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works.  It could likely be done more elegantly, but I'm pretty sure it works for any input values, making only a single pass:

```
a = [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
b = [4, 5, 6]
i = 1
while True:
    if i == len(a):
        for v in b:
            a.append((None, v))
        break
    while len(b) and a[i][1] >= b[0]:
        v = b.pop(0)
        if a[i][1] > v:
            a.insert(i, (None, v))
            i += 1
    i += 1
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[(1, None), (2, 4), (None, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Tried it with more input too:

```
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

which gives you:

```
[(1, None), (2, 4), (None, 5), (None, 6), (None, 7), (3, 8), (None, 9), (None, 10)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I tried your code, but it encountered errors at the last two if sentences, since it is comparable when a[i][1]==None.

Comment: Huh?  You mean the code above, or with different inputs?  I ran the code above.  It works.  It's never looking at the value of the first item in the tuples. a[i][1] is always an integer. - Look again.  I have a better answer anyway...

Comment: Oops.  You're right!  The first element.  This is only a problem with Python 3.  I was using 2.7.  I fixed the code so it starts after the first element, which makes it work in Python 3.

Comment: I tried your latest code. The same error also occurred: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'. I think it's because when i=0, a[i][1] is none and thus can't be compared with b[0] in the second "while" sentence.

Comment: You tried it after I changed **i=0** to **i=1**?  The code that's now posted is running for me under Python 3.  I changed the code twice.  The first time, I changed the algorithm,  The second time, I made it Python 3 compatible.

Comment: What if another None pops up as the lists grow? For instance, a=[(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4,None),(5,9)], b=[4,5,6,7,8,9].

Comment: Your problem definition does not say that there will ever be other **None** entries in the list (in the second tuple element). If there were, wouldn't they have to all be at the front so that the sorting was still right, with None appearing before 0?  It would be trivial to skip past all the None entries at the start of the list if there were more than 1.  Your problem definition states that there is always one there, so I just hard coded the 1 value.  Easy to change.  If there were (*, None) entries elsewhere in the list, it would be easy to check for that and skip them.

Comment: Even if you came back and processed the list again with more entries to insert, there would never be more (*, None) entries, right?  This is because you're inserting only numbers, and those get put in the second position in the new tuple.

Comment: I have to leave some work for you to do :) . If you need to insert other types of values than just numbers, I'm sure you can update this code to allow for that.

Comment: Btw, thanks for this!  It was an interesting problem, and a  fun thing to think about.  I like working with small but interesting problems.

Comment: Sorry for not stating it clearly in the problem definition. Actually, this is a matching problem. Imagine two columns where there can be values in column one that is not matched with values in column two (thus matched with None) and vice versa. List "a" has listed the match from the perspective of column one. The goal here is to add in the perspective of column two by filling in those values in column two that does not have a match in column one. Hope my explanation clarifies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190549/discussion-between-steve-and-molly-zhou).